# How to open more than 2 files in a single Emacs frame?

Tags: emacs

I would like to be able to automate the process of opening several files in emacs under a single frame, so that the frame splits up into multiple windows. Currently I am only able to open 2 files in a single emacs frame (2 windows) by typing this in a linux terminal: `emacs file1 file2`. However, if I try to open more than 2 files, for example by typing `emacs file1 file2 file3` then it will open file3 in one window and in the other window it will come up with a 'CRM buffer' which lists the files in the directory.

How do I get it to open more than 2 files, so that the emacs frame is split up into more than 2 windows?

Note that 'window' means window in the emacs sense, not in the MS windows sense (frames).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the buffer list from coming up by setting `inhibit-startup-buffer-menu` to `t` as described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Action-Arguments.html#Action-Arguments). However, that still does not result in more than 2 windows. Looking at the initialization code in `startup.el`, this does not seem to be customizable.

However, the [`ibuffer`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode) command `ibuffer-do-view` (bound to <kbd>v</kbd>) displays multiple buffers in the way you want. You can use it programatically. Put this in your `.emacs` file:

```
(defun view-files-in-windows ()
  (ibuffer)                      ; Activate ibuffer mode.
  (ibuffer-mark-special-buffers) ; Mark the special buffers.
  (ibuffer-toggle-marks)         ; Toggle buffers, leaving the non-special ones
  (ibuffer-do-view))             ; Show each buffer in a different window.
```

Then run emacs like this:

```
$ emacs file1 file2 file3 file4 --eval "(view-files-in-windows)"
```

(It fails if there are too many files and the windows would become too small.)

Comment: Nice one thanks! Is there a way to start it so that the 4 windows appear in 2 rows instead of one column?

Comment: @Eddy: Please consider upvoting answers you accept, as the answer probably *was* helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with `ibuffer`, but if your files are sequentially numbered, [grid-files-sq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11441270/1404208) might be something like what you're looking for, or you can use [GridLayout](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GridLayout)